# onkeypress to recognize current div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple contenteditable div with `onkeypress` event like below:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcx7mmxo/)

```
<script>
function hadd(event){   
        var val = event.charCode;               
        if(val == 36){//$ sign  
            var current  = $(this);             
            console.log("val_c: " + val);
            console.log("rh: " + current);        
            current.append("correct");
        }           
    };
</script>

 <div class="example" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1" onkeypress="hadd(event);">Test</div>
 <div class="example" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1" onkeypress="hadd(event);">Test_2</div>
 <div class="example" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1" onkeypress="hadd(event);">Test_3</div>
```

What I want is for the `hadd(event)` to recognize "`$(this)`". What change should I make? Because I am getting `createDocumentFragement` error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a second parameter and pass the current element.

```
onkeypress="hadd(event, this);"
```

And in your code:

```
function hadd(event, which) {
    current = $(which);
    //...
}
```

Or in simple way, you can also use:

```
function hadd(event) {
    current = $(event.target);
    //...
}
```

**Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wxwz7bab/**

Comment: No problem. I got another question and could you check if you can help with it? Its about contenteditable (such a pain).. lol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965018/contenteditable-enter-behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var current  = $(this);
```

to

```
var current  = $(event.target);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function hadd(event) {
    var current = $(event.target);
    //...
}
```