# Contenteditable enter behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I have contenteditable setup as below:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cctv3zv9/2/)

```
<div class="top" contenteditable="true">
   <div class="inner" contenteditable="true" tabindex="-1">
      Good 
      <span class="bot">Awesome</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

In this setup, there are two `contenteditble` div inside of another. Inside of `inner` div, there is a `bot` span.

When enter is pressed outside of this `bot` class **(Case 1 or 2 in jsfiddle)**, it creates an identical `inner` div with the `bot` span while previous `inner` div does not have `bot` span anymore, which makes sense.

**Example: Case 1 or 2 (Good)**

```
 <div class="top"...>
   <div class="inner"...>Good</div>
   <div class="inner"...>&nbsp;<span class="bot">Awesome</span></div>
</div>
```

However when enter is pressed inside of `bot` span **(Case 3 or 4)**, then it creates an identical `inner` div along with the `bot` span WHILE the previous `inner` div still have `bot` span.

**Example: Case 3 or 4 (Problem)**

```
 <div class="top"...>
   <div class="inner"...>Good<span class="bot">Awesome</span></div>
   <div class="inner"...><span class="bot"><br></span></div>
 </div>
```

What I want to achieve is that when enter is pressed INSIDE of `bot` span, I want to create an identical `inner` div WITHOUT the `bot` span like below:

```
<div class="top"...>
   <div class="inner"...>Good<span class="bot">Awesome</span></div>
   <div class="inner"...>&nbsp;</div> //No `bot` span
 </div>
```

or..

```
 <div class="top"...>
   <div class="inner"...>Good<span class="bot">Awe</span></div> //enter between 'awesome'
   <div class="inner"...>some</div> //No `bot` span
 </div>
```

I did some research but was not able to find a good answer. Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is pretty much the way browsers handle things. I am not sure how to solve it. Let's leave it to others.

Comment: yeah, looks that way. Thanks though! =)